# Can I use Markdown syntax to compose e-mails in MoonMail?

Tags: markdown, commonmark, moonmail

[MoonMail](https://moonmail.io/) uses the Liquid templating engine for rendering e-mails. Is there a way I can use Markdown/CommonMark syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of [MoonMail](https://moonmail.io) you can use only **plain html** with [liquid syntax](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers). The next version of MoonMail will come with a fully featured [open source drag & drop editor](https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail-editor) which will support many templating engines.